# Not booting ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, bios

I was nicely using Ubuntu14.04 but due to some software requirements I had to upgrade and also install NVIDIA so when I reboot, I am unable to see a GUI screen and while trying Ctr+Alt+F1, the login is not accepting. When tried repairing using DVD prepared from ubuntu14.04 iso file, the repair option is not coming. When tried the same with higher version, some BIOS error was showed before starting ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** "Some error" can be quite easily fixed by doing "something". (cheeky way of saying that we need more info like exact kernel version, error messages, ... so please [edit] your question as now **the question is unclear**.

Answer (score 0):

Press esc after boot bios, before booting the kernel.
And select the boot safemode.

Comment: Could not perform the above said operations on my HP Proliant Server. Any other option please.

Comment: You see "Loading operating system" after loading BIOS? In this moment press ESC repeatedly.